# Issue with PHP getimagesize script

Tags: php, if-statement, echo, getimagesize

I'm working on this simple script which finds an image url based upon database values then echos that to display the image, or if no image is available a default image.

However there is something wrong as it returns the default image every-time.  If I replace the default echo line with the $image line, it displays.  So from that I know it can find the URL of the image.

```
<?php
$image = CONST_IMG_URL.$FetchData['capcode'].".jpg";            
error_reporting(0);

if (getimagesize($image)) {
echo "<a href='$image'><img src=\"$image\" width='300' height='150'/></a>";
} 

else {
echo "<img src='".plugins_url()."/plugins/images/image_not_found.jpg'     width='300' height='150'/>";}
?>
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what the image url looks like? Do you have spaces in the image name? If so you need to encode it properly (image%20name.jpg)

Comment: Why are you using `getimagesize` to determine if you should show the image? - `file_exists` is probably what you want

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `getimagesize` isn't doing anything productive.. I would suggest using `file_exists`..

In order to have `file_exists` work correctly - you need to give the full path (not a URI).

So you could do something like: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/images/' . $image;`

like so:

```
if(file_exists( '/full/path/to/image/dir/' . $image ))
{
    echo "<a href='$image'><img src=\"$image\" width='300' height='150'/></a>";
} else {
    echo "<img src='".plugins_url()."/plugins/images/image_not_found.jpg' width='300' height='150'/>";
}
```

**Explanation**

[**`getimagesize`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) - This returns an `array` of attributes relating to the image, rather than explicitly returning if the image exists or not, in fact, if the image does not exist it will throw a warning rather than returning `false` as you'd expect.

[**`file_exists`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) - this checks for the file, and returns `true` if it exists, and `false` if the file does not exist - this is exactly what you're looking for in your scenario

Answer (score 0):

You should use next code:

```
try {
    $img = @getimagesize($image);
    echo "<a href='$image'><img src=\"$image\" width='300' height='150'/></a>";
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "<img src='".plugins_url()."/plugins/images/image_not_found.jpg'     width='300' height='150'/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, your `CONST_IMG_URL` is a path that's relative to the website - not the file-system.

The [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) method finds images on the file-system itself using relative or absolute path names (i.e. `/var/www/images/uploaded/pic.jpg` or `images/uploaded/pic.jpg`). It can also find images via URLs such as `http://example.com/images/uploaded/pic.jpg`.

If `CONST_IMG_URL` is a path, without the domain portion, `getimagesize()` will look at the file-system for that image and there's a good chance that it doesn't exist. For instance, if `CONST_IMG_URL` is `/images/uploaded/`, the method will check on the server for that absolute path - which won't exist as it treats the leading `/` as "the root of the server", not "inside your website's folder".

To remedy this, you can take two approaches (if you want to keep using `getimagesize()`).

1. The first is the make `CONST_IMG_URL` an absolute path that includes your domain:

   ```
   define('CONST_IMG_URL', 'http://domain.com/images/uploaded');
   ```
2. The second would be to append the full document-root to the path when you're calling getimagesize():

   ```
   if (getimagesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $image)) {
   ```

If you're going to go with #2 above, I would actually recommend using a different method, [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) instead. This function will simply check if the file exists opposed to loading the file to pull parameter information out of it (width, height, etc) and will make page-loads slightly more efficient =].

Answer (score 0):

You should use file_exists function instead of getimagesize:

```
<?php
$image = CONST_IMG_URL.$FetchData['capcode'].".jpg";            
error_reporting(0);

if (file_exists($image)) {
  echo "<a href='$image'><img src=\"$image\" width='300' height='150'/></a>";
} 
else {
  echo "<img src='".plugins_url()."/plugins/images/image_not_found.jpg'     width='300' height='150'/>";}
?>
```